# Adiabatic sound speed in static spherically-symmetric perfect-fluid solutions (SSSPF) of Einstein field equations (EFE)

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, symmetry, acoustics, adiabatic

Why $\sqrt{dp/d\rho}$ is interpreted in SSSPF solutions as adiabatic speed of sound although the corresponding equations are static? In static world all times derivatives are zero and without wave equation sound cannot propagate. Similar situation arises by trying to prove that $c=1/\sqrt{\epsilon_{0} \mu_{0}}$, using only Maxwell's static equations.

Answer (score 1):

If the system is truly static then there can be no sound, as you mention.  However, acoustics is a perturbation analysis from the static case.  The description of the miniscule motion of acoustics relies entirely on properties of the truly static case, which is common in perturbation analyses.  In this case $\sqrt{dp/d\rho}$, which is a feature of the static fluid, is the speed that waves with infinitesimal amplitude would propagate if such motion were allowed.  No wave needs to be present for its theoretical speed to be identified.

Comment: Michael, thanks a lot for your answer. The reason for my question is the demand of subluminal sound speed to prove the physicality of some static EFE solution. I almost agree with you but would like to understand how such perturbation analysis can be carried out without time dependence. Or much simple, how perturbation analysis of static Maxwell equation allows to identify $c$ as $1/\sqrt{\epsilon_{0} \mu_{0}}$.

Comment: If you are only given the static equations you wouldn't be able to identify a unique wave speed, because you have assumed a priori that there is no motion of any sort.  You need to start with dynamic equations and do the perturbation from there.  An example that would lead to wildly different wave solutions but have the same static equations are (a) $u'=-\dot p$ and $p'=-\dot u$, and (b) $u'=-\dddot p$ and $p'=-\dot u$.

Comment: It is what I have thought, too. One needs some dynamic equation to do the perturbation analysis. Your example is very good to talk about this problem. The traditionally imposed physicality criteria for static spherically-symmetric solutions of Einstein field equations usually demand a subluminal speed of sound. Something, what I find not necessary. Thanks!